# Find and replace first occurrence of a space

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Given a line of text with two words, such as:

**hi hello**

How can I replace the first occurrence of a space with a comma, giving desired result:

**hi, hello**

Sublime text regex `^([^\s]*)(\s)` gives:

`hi`hello

Where the gray represents the selected area (notice it's also including the word `hi`, when it should only include the first space for replacing), which if I ran find replace on, would give:

**, hello**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You capture up to the space and include the captured content in your replacement.

Find what: `^(\S*)\s`
Replace with: `\1,`

Comment: How can I ignore line breaks? It's adding `,` to those lines

Comment: If you don't have tabs in your data, you could use a space instead of `\s`.

Comment: One more thing - how can I replace the first occurrence of a character? Given `佟, 佟, Tong2, /surname Tong/`, I want to replace the first occurrence of `/`. To do this, I'm using `^[^/]*/` But it's replacing everything preceding the first `/` including the `/` itself. Leaving me with `surname Tong/`

Comment: You're missing the parentheses used to capture the content up to your character.  `^([^/]*)/`.

Comment: why do I need those parenthesis?

Comment: You use the parentheses to capture everything from the start of the line up to that first occurrence.  It will capture that content into the variable, `\1'.  You replace with '\1' followed by your desired change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136662/discussion-between-growler-and-phatfingers).